# Cant locate Android SDK

Tags: android, sdk, android-sdk-tools

I get a message stating 'please provide the path to android sdk' When I try to start the Android Studio.

I tried uninstalling and re-installing but nothing happens.

Comment: Please proved more detail. OS? Version of Android Studio?

Comment: Did you install install the android sdk in the sdk manager?

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty clear where the problem is: You have to locate (or download) the Android sdk. Start the SDK Manager in Android Studio and download the latest sdk.